# Drawing a RegionPlot but for data instead of a function

Tags: plotting, graphics, data, list-manipulation

I am trying to draw something similar to `RegionPlot`, but instead of functions I only have data matrices. For example, I have the following 3 pieces of data (simplified for this question) and I want to show the 3 regions where one is larger than the other two. That is, I want to plot the 3 regions where `{EAR>SDM && EAR>ADMC}`, `{SDM>EAR && SDM>ADMC}`, `{ADMC>EAR && ADMC>SDM}`:

```
EAR = {{0.107749, 0.107749, 0.107749}, {0.0744855, 0.0713607, 0.069264},  
 {0.0581068, 0.0537309, 0.0508256}}

SDM = {{0.0514403, 0.0377929, 0.0289352}, {0.0514403, 0.0377929, 0.0289352}, 
 {0.0514403, 0.0377929, 0.0289352}}

ADMC = {{0.077505, 0.0689003, 0.062779}, {0.0659348, 0.0579942, 0.052373}, 
 {0.0572223, 0.0498253, 0.0446134}}
```

What I would like to produce is a region plot similar to this one here which I produced using the `RegionPlot` command and functions that are very similar (but not exactly like) to the data given above (and obviously a lot more intermediate points drawn by the *Mathematica* `RegionPlot` command).

[image: RegionPlot with functions]

I produced this plot with this code:

```
RegionPlot[{EARstar[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] > SDM[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] 
  && EARstar[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] > ADMC[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k], 
  SDM[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] > EARstar[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] && 
  SDM[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] > ADMC[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k], 
  ADMC[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] > EARstar[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] && 
  ADMC[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] > SDM[delta, r, sigma, rho, lambda, k] && }, 
 {lambda, 1, 2}, {r, 1, 10}]
```

While the commands `ListLinePlot` and `ListPlot3D` do pretty much exactly the same as `Plot` and `Plot3D` the command `ListRegionPlot` does not exist.

It was easy for me to draw data similar (but more detailed) to the one listed above with `ListPlot3D` (see image below) but I would really prefer the simpler 2D visualization of a command similar to `RegionPlot`.

[image: Similar data drawn with ListPlot3D command]

Is there a workaround I could use?

Comment: Probably I'm been silly here but I don't understand how are `EAR`, `SDM`, and `ADMC` defining regions.

Comment: You can achieve a decent 2D projection effect with your `ListPlot3D` approach with the following options: `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 
  Infinity}, Mesh -> None, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", 
   White}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> {True, True, False}`.

Comment: @shrx That's great and does EXACTLY what I want. The only downside is that I can't enlarge it after drawing it because any click on the diagram will destroy the ViewPoint.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I figured out how to do it by setting `ImageSize -> Large`

Comment: @Achwiegutdassniemandweiß What I don't understand is, how can a `ListPlot3D` solution that @shrx gives be *exactly what you want*, when you explicitly ask of the `RegionPlot` method? Can we close this question or are still interested in an answer to your original question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very easy way is to interpolate your data matrices so that you can use them like normal functions. Let me give a simple example where `data1` and `data2` are supposed to be your *data matrices*:

```
data1 = Table[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -1, 1, 2/10}, {y, -1, 1, 2/10}];
data2 = Table[2 Sin[2 x + 2 y], {x, -1, 1, 2/10}, {y, -1, 1, 2/10}];
ListPlot3D[{data1, data2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we want to find the region where the golden surface is above the blue one and for this, we simply interpolate the matrices and use `RegionPlot` as usual:

```
{f1, f2} = ListInterpolation[#, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] & /@ {data1, data2};
RegionPlot[f1[x, y] > f2[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When your data is large, then you might have to watch whether the performance is still acceptable. One way to speed things up is to reduce the `InterpolationOrder` to 1 or 2.